# Java move mouse

Tags: java, mouse

I'm writing an application that will teach the basics of using a computer and I need to move the mouse to show what you have to do. I tried this:

```
public static void click(Point p) throws AWTException{
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.mouseMove(p.x, p.y);
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e) {}
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Everything works, but the mouse teleports to the specified coordinates, without moving. So my question is: How effectively simulate the movement of the mouse, clicking the left and right and draging and dropping (as if you held the mouse button)

Comment: do you change the x and y ?

Comment: How do i have to chane it? when i invoke it, i'm giving coordinates as p and mouse is clicking in this coordinates, but it does not approaching the coordinates. It just teleport and then clicking. What i want is  first physically moved to the specified coordinates, and then clicked. I mean, I'd like to see that moves, not just jump from one place to another

Comment: ahh that's because it is  happening  so fast .you have to use a loop and increment coordinate by small values

Comment: ok, but how to do it? and how to make right click and drag and drop operation?

Comment: Separate it into tasks. The part that moves the mouse is going to be looped and incremented. Then use that as the basis of click, right-click and drag-and-drop.

Comment: I understand how it should work, but I make all this application to crash-course in Java and I do not quite know how to do it in code ...

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ok, I have right and left click and drag and drop, but i can't find a way to slow down the mouse

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void click(Point p) throws AWTException{
    Robot r = new Robot();
    gradualMouseMove(p, r);
    r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e) {}
    r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
    private static void gradualMouseMove(Point pointIn, Robot robot) throws InterruptedException {
    //TO ADJUST SPEED OF MOVEMENT
    //CHANGE:   1:sleep duration   2:deltaX #   3:deltaY #
    Point mouseLocation;        //Point for updating the currentLocation
    int deltaX;                 //X coordinate update value
    int deltaY;                 //Y coordinate update value
    boolean xInProgess = true;  //Stop condition for X
    boolean yInProgess = true;  //Stop condition for Y
    do{
        //update Mouse Location
        mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    //calculate X coordinates
        if(pointIn.getX() - mouseLocation.getX() > 2){  
            deltaX = 1;    //Mouse is LEFT of Destination
        }else if (pointIn.getX() - mouseLocation.getX() < -2){
            deltaX = -1;    //Mouse is RIGHT of Destination
        }else{
            xInProgess = false;     //X Done
            deltaX = 0;
        }
    //calculate Y coordinates
        if(pointIn.getY() - mouseLocation.getY() > 2){
            deltaY = 1;    //Mouse is ABOVE Destination
        }else if (pointIn.getY() - mouseLocation.getY() < -2){
            deltaY = -1;    //Mouse is BELOW Destination
        }else{
            yInProgess = false;    //Y Done
            deltaY = 0;
        }
        //move mouse on Screen by adjustment amount
        robot.mouseMove((int)(mouseLocation.getX()+deltaX), (int)(mouseLocation.getY()+deltaY));
        Thread.sleep(6);     //pause to slow down movement
    }while(xInProgess || yInProgess);   //loop until complete on X & Y
}
```

The above method gradualMouseMove is a simple version of "SLIDING" the mouse to a destination point.

*****Care that you do not use a point OFF your screen.  This my prevent the loop from exiting if the mouse never gets there.  You can add a count to end at a certain value if this is an issue.******

** Addition - You could add some math in there to have it go in a straight line to the destination if you like. (rather than the plateau currently there) **

This should give you a launch pad however.